# How to find car rental companies in Kalibo, Philippines?

Tags: car-rentals, buses, philippines

How can I find a rental car in Kalibo, Philippines?

Google didn't turn up anything useful.

Is it even a good idea to try to find one, or should I just take cabs and buses to explore Panay?

Comment: Try checking out olx.ph. Personally, exploring while commuting is definitely more exciting.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I'd try and do what the locals do, and use their transport - it'll be more fun and you'll meet people that you wouldn't get to if you were driving your own car.  Plus you won't get lost, and you'll be able to look around and enjoy what you're seeing.

According to perennial favourite [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Kalibo), vans (or L3s as they are called there) cost about 80 pesos per person from Caticlan to Kalibo and they take approximately 45 minutes to 1 hour. Look for an air conditioned van (which might come at a slightly inflated price of 10 to 20 pesos more per person).  That gives you a rough price guide at least to bargain for - I suspect you may have to come prepared to negotiate ;)

There's also Jeepneys - a Jeepney to Kalibo from Caticlan takes about 1 to 1.5 hours and will cost you about 45 Pesos.  Find them at Jeepney-Php 45, FX Taxi- Php 90,Terminal Roxas Ave. Street Kalibo, or use the Aklan Shuttle Bus-Php 100 up,Terminal Airport

And what sounds the most fun to me:  Motorized tricycles will take you just about anywhere in Kalibo for a standard rate of 6.50 Pesos (6 Pesos 50 Centavos). Foreigners are commonly asked for much higher rates but the drivers must accept the 6.50 peso rate by law.

Comment: Worth noting, 6.50 is the _flagdown_ rate, then additional per several hundred meters, or kilometer, depending on the area. See [this](http://www.mb.com.ph/node/327727/qc-) for a recent fare hike. Areas under the tourism authority _require_ 'trikes' (as we call them) to clearly post the fare, it's usually on a laminated poster board attached to the inside of the side car. If you don't see one, don't get in. If the driver wants more than 50 pesos for a 2 - 3 kilometer ride, he's ripping you off. I agree, renting a car would be silly.

Comment: Renting a car is not only simply a way to get your body from A to B. When you rent a car, you can keep your stuff in it (like heavy food you want to eat on the way of your trip or at your destination, for example 10 coconuts) when travelling around and you don't have to carry everything on your back when you go visit some place. If you want to go hiking in remote areas, Jeepneys will rarely go there or not at all, and a dedicated driver, waiting for you 12 hours while you climb somewhere and back would be cost prohibitive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a local place that advertises on facebook.  I've never used them and therefore can not vouch for them but you can check it out. It says they are located in the area you are interested in.

https://www.facebook.com/betsyrentalcarservices/